# Disable file cache for mount point

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-cache

I ran into a bug similar to this one:

[RHEL NFS client returns NULL bytes when reading a growing file](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/22717)

So my solution was to check for \0 Bytes and reread the file. Problem here is, that the wrong file, which includes the \0 Bytes, is cached on the system where the java application runs. So it takes quite a while to read the correct file contents.

When I do a `sync && echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` it immediately reads the correct content.

I tried to add `sync` to the NFS mount options without a difference.

Is it possible to disable the file cache for a specific mount point? If so, how to do that?

Comment: That content is not available to everyone. What did it tell you to do? And what did you do afterward?

Comment: I don't have a redhat account. So I don't know what their workaround is. I just added it because it contains a very good description of the problem.

Comment: I just want to disable cache to avoid reading external SD cards to fill the RAM and push away other cached data.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Resolution
>
> This issue was discussed with Red Hat Engineering under Private Bug 702085, but was not able to be repaired within the RHEL 5 product lifecycle.
>
> Red Hat Product Management have elected not to repair this issue within RHEL 6 for the following reasons:
>
> - Customer exposure to this issue is not significant.
> - This behaviour is documented on the Customer Portal along with workarounds.
> - This behaviour is much harder (takes longer) to reproduce in RHEL 6 compared to RHEL 5.
> - The NFS protocol does not guarantee cache coherence.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> - Ensure one client cannot read a file while another client is accessing it by using file locks, such as flock in shell scripts, or `fcntl()` in C.
> - Open the file with `O_DIRECT` so that the page cache is avoided.
> - Do not read past the **EOF**.
> - For example, in Python use `os.stat()` to get the file size, `os.open()` to open the file and `os.read()` to read only up to the file size.
> - Avoid running `tail -f` on files residing on NFS mounts.
> - If using RHEL 5, the `sync` mount option will also avoid this issue. This will not work in RHEL6, as the `nfs_readpage_sync()` function was removed upstream in between RHEL 5 and RHEL 6, so that function does not exist in RHEL 6.